Why can't I texture paint all faces from any angle?
When I try to texture paint an object the brush has little to no effect on faces that are angled away from the viewport camera. I have tried the "Occlude" and "Backface Culling" settings and starting my line in different spots, but the only way around it I have is to change the camera to make the faces less angled. Is there a way around this besides adjusting the camera?


Maybe look at upping the Falloff Angle to 90 degrees

